# Are there technical reasons EF 5 isn't fully supported on .NET4.0?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

I wanted to upgrade my app to EF 5 to take advantage of features like support for enum spatial etc. However, I was not able to upgrade unless I move to .Net 4.5.

I would like to know what features of .Net 4.5 does EF 5 use that it can not be done in .Net 4.0?

Comment: I hope that the updated title makes it a "constructive" question. However, even if something is *technically* feasible, it might not be *practically* feasible to support multiple targets (imagine if it uses just *one* new "convenience" 4.5 API call), especially when trying to promote the latest-and-greatest .. also, going from .NET4.0 to .NET4.5 isn't a "CLR-breaking" change, like .NET3.5 to .NET4 (or .NET1.1 to .NET2) was.

Comment: One immediate example of that: supporting 2 frameworks immediately doubles the testing required (everything needs testing on each framework), **even if** you aren't aware of any technical issues.

Comment: [You can install EF5 for .NET4.0 via NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/entityframework), but you probably won't get all the features.

Comment: Yes. I am aware of that. What I am looking for is the features of .net 4.5 that EF5 uses to support specifically enums & spatial.

Comment: @Hemant Make sure to include (and sometimes emphasis) such information the question itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My understanding is that EF >= 4.1 (including EF 5) consists of

- the EF "core libraries" like (`System.Data.Entity.dll`) which are part of the .NET Framework
- the additional package/assembly you can download via Nuget which contains the `DbContext` API and Code-First development

There were plans and an attempt in summer 2011 (the [Entity Framework June 2011 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx)) to release the `enum`, spatial support and other new features (except Code-First Migrations) as an update of the core librares before .NET 4.5 is released. But the EF team has decided that such out-of-band updates are possible for the NuGet package (that's why EF 4.3 already has the Migrations feature that didn't require to touch the core libraries), but for the core libraries they are too difficult and can't be done before .NET 4.5 release:

> There are two logical parts to the Entity Framework, the core
>   components that ship inside the .NET Framework and Visual Studio and
>   the ‘out of band’ components that we can update on a much more
>   frequent schedule. We are currently looking at how we can update the
>   core components on a more frequent cadence as well. The ‘EF June 2011
>   CTP’ was our first attempt at shipping the core components more
>   frequently and it’s become clear we’re just not technically ready to
>   do this yet.
>
> Core components include:
>
> - Core EF Runtime (System.Data.Entity.dll & System.Web.Entity.dll)
> - EF Designer
>
> Out of band components include: (We will likely ship more out of band
>   components in the future)
>
> - The DbContext API & Code First (EntityFramework.dll)
> - T4 Templates for using DbContext API with Model First & Database First
> - EF Power Tools
> - Code First Migrations

(Quote from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/08/09/ef-releases-amp-versioning-call-for-feedback.aspx).)

That means that `enum` support for EF will be part of the .NET 4.5 core libraries and not of the downloadable EF 5 NuGet package. Hence the new EF features like `enum` and spatial support are not available together with .NET 4.0.

More about the history and reason of separating "EF Core libraries" from "EF NuGet package" is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/10/18/how-we-talk-about-ef-and-its-future-versions.aspx

Comment: So what I understand is that the team wanted the non code first libraries to be able to take advantage of enum, spatial support etc. In such case releasing an SP which would update VS 2010 would have been a cheaper option. Forcing projects to move to .Net 4.5 and there by asking developers to move to VS 2012 in span of just 2 years without major change in runtime is like running behind money. I know VS 2012 is a much better product. :) I just hope that they reduce the price of VS 2012 upgrade drastically. But I am happy that going forward, ASP.Net and EF are going open source.

Comment: @Hemant At least it isn't like the auto-up "feature" of MSTest projects .. want a .NET35 test in VS2010? :(

Comment: @Hemant: I found some more quotes and resources and included in my answer. But nothing really new there.