# Nullable enum field with Code First Approach doesn't create the enum Field in Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am using the code first approach to create the schema and then populating the data in it with the help of Seed method

I am using Entity Framework Version 5.0,SQLEXPRESS2008 and MVC4

below is my Model

```
  public enum Grade
{
    A, B, C, D, F
}

public class Enrollment
{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No grade")]
    public Grade? Grade { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

this is how i populate the data to the Database using seed method in Intializer

```
 var enrollments = new List<Enrollment>
        {
        new Enrollment{StudentID=1,CourseID=1050,Grade=Grade.A},
        new Enrollment{StudentID=1,CourseID=4022,Grade=Grade.C},
        new Enrollment{StudentID=1,CourseID=4041,Grade=Grade.B},
        new Enrollment{StudentID=2,CourseID=1045,Grade=Grade.B},
        new Enrollment{StudentID=2,CourseID=3141,Grade=Grade.F},
        new Enrollment{StudentID=2,CourseID=2021,Grade=Grade.F},
        new Enrollment{StudentID=3,CourseID=1050},
        new Enrollment{StudentID=4,CourseID=1050,},
        new Enrollment{StudentID=4,CourseID=4022,Grade=Grade.F},
        new Enrollment{StudentID=5,CourseID=4041,Grade=Grade.C},
        new Enrollment{StudentID=6,CourseID=1045},
        new Enrollment{StudentID=7,CourseID=3141,Grade=Grade.A},
        };
        enrollments.ForEach(s => context.Enrollments.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

on debug ,I am able to see the data in "Grade" Column within that  context

but it neither creates the Column "Grade" in Database nor populates its data.

I have setup the Context and Database Initalizer as below in my web.config

```
   <entityFramework>
  <context type="EntityFrameworkWithMVC.DAL.SchoolContext, EntityFrameworkWithMVC">
    <databaseInitializer type="EntityFrameworkWithMVC.DAL.SchoolInitializer,  EntityFrameworkWithMVC" />
    </context>
   </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: yes I have set it in web.config.Schema is created with in DB .but only this field is not being created.

Comment: please review the modified post.Do you want me to put whole Intializer class?

Comment: Sorry, my bad: is it only the `Grade` column that's missing? Did you add it after an initial database creation? If so; try to recreate the database by deleting it manually. If the `Grade` field is created, it must be you migration strategy. Final thing: are you using .NET 4.5? it is required for the `enum` functionality in EF5

Comment: I have repeated that procedure of recreating the Database 4-5 times.but it is not helping.FYI.its nullable type. I am using .NET framework version 4.0.Yes its also given in Contoso University Example on Asp.net site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need .NET 4.5

Enum support is not available in EF 5 with .NET 4.0. This is due to a change in System.Data.Entity which is located not in the EF 5 library but in the .NET 4.5 version.

See:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/55dc58a4-6190-4bad-b317-1787cf86bf3d/ef-5-but-no-enum-support?forum=adodotnetentityframework

[Are there technical reasons EF 5 isn't fully supported on .NET4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594289/are-there-technical-reasons-ef-5-isnt-fully-supported-on-net4-0)

You'll need a workaround to extract your `enum` value (you can use `int` and convert to `enum` in your mappings) or upgrade to .NET 4.5

[UPDATE]
As for a workaround, there are a couple of options,
In all cases you'll need to write your `enum` value as a `string` or `int` (or other supported type) to the database:

- Use a mapper

If you are using a ViewModel or something similar you can implement a configurable mapper like AutoFac (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/). It's a bit hard to use at first but it has all the features for IOC, MVC etc. You can define a custom mapping definition so that you can use the `enum` in your ViewModel and the `int` value in your entity. The custom mapping contains the conversion from `int` to `enum` and back.

- Use a [NotMapped] column

This is faster to implement, but it usually bites you in the tail:

```
public int? GradeValue {get;set;}

[NotMapped]
[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No grade")]
public Grade? Grade 
{ 
    get 
    { 
         return GradeValue.HasValue ? (Grade?) GradeValue.Value : null; 
    } 
}
```

The [NotMapped] attribute ensures the `enum` is not added to the database (might come in handy if you'll decide to upgrade to .NET 4.5 later on).

Now you can read the value as an `enum`. My guess is that `GradeValue` needs to be public (private/protected would give you some advantages) (not sure if supported in this version). If it has to be `public`; its kind of tricky because other developers might use this `GradeValue` directly.

Alternatively you can do something similar for the `set` instruction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @HarshilGandhi: There are, but it depends on your code/project. I will update the post.

Comment: Thanks for the help stefan.I am converting it to int after assigning integer value to each enum value.that works now.